# Can't change Featured Products Image Size (Magento)

Tags: magento

In the Admin page, I can't see an option anywhere to change how the feature products in the "Home" page are shown, I want the images to be bigger but I can't find an option anywhere (Not even in the "manage products" or "atributes" sections)

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the template. This cannot be achieved via configuration.
Every product image is resized/generated and saved in image cache so it depends on how the image helper function is called from within the template.